# Nautilus compare in 20.04

Tags: software-installation, nautilus, context-menu

Up to 18.04 it was possible to install nautilus-compare to get a context menu that provide a compare later and compare to option.  Now that I'm trying an upgrade to 20.04 I'm wondering how to do this in Focal.  I assume it can be done using the fma-config-tool, but if someone has done it already,  I'd like to avoid trying to invent an inferior wheel myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 20200522:** the package is available [in PPA](https://launchpad.net/~boamaod/+archive/ubuntu/nautilus-compare?field.series_filter=focal) and is installable by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:boamaod/nautilus-compare
sudo apt-get install nautilus-compare
```

---

The package [was removed](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nautilus-compare) from official Ubuntu 20.04 LTS repository.

But you can still download package from 19.10 manually and install it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/nautilus-compare/nautilus-compare_0.0.4+po1-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./nautilus-compare_0.0.4+po1-1_all.deb
```

then restart Nautilus and use it as before.

Answer (score 4):

The package was most likely removed from 20.04 because it depended on Python 2, which is also no longer available in Focal.

The code has been [updated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-compare/+bug/1770630) to support Python 3 though. I'm not sure if/when it will return to the main repo, but the updated package is available in [Märt Põder's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~boamaod/+archive/ubuntu/nautilus-compare).